# pip and pip3 - both pointing to python3.5?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I started to experiment with [shade](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/shade/index.html) today; and installed it for both python2 and python3 on my ubuntu 16.04 system; using:

```
sudo pip install shade
```

respectively

```
sudo pip3 install shade
```

Both commands passed; I didn't really pay attention.

Then I tried to run this little test script:

```
from shade import *

simple_logging(debug=True)
conn = openstack_cloud(cloud='myopenstack')
images = conn.list_images()
for image in images:
  print(image)
```

Using python3, I got a certificate error (which is fine, I would be rather surprised to find our *internal* infrastructure to use correct certificates).

But just to be sure, I wanted to run with python2.7, too; and I am told:

> ImportError: No module named shade

So, I had a closer look what pip and pip3 have to say:

```
> pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
> pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

It looks like both `pip` and `pip3` are actually working on my python3 installation, but when I do:

```
 > python --version
 Python 2.7.12
 > python3 --version
 Python 3.5.2
```

Any idea, anybody? What could be causing this, or how to actually install *shade* for python2/pip?

As requested:

```
> for i in pip pip3 python python3 ; do type $i ; done
pip is /usr/local/bin/pip
pip3 is /usr/local/bin/pip3
python is /usr/bin/python
python3 is /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: Would you mind running `for i in pip pip3 python python3 ; do type $i ; done`  and add the result to your question?

Comment: added that information.

Comment: `pip3` looks like the default option `pip` uses. Do you not have `pip2`?

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/pip` exist?

Comment: @kichik Uups, there is a `pyp2`, too. And that works, two. Thanks. If you make that an answer, you will sure get my upvote for that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pip3` looks like the default option `pip` uses. Try using `pip2` instead to explicitly install a Python 2 package.

Comment: Had the same problem and pip2 worked for me as well.

Comment: couldnt thank you enough.. I have been struggling with the python module installations for the two versions for so long... life's gonna be so much better now..

Answer (score 8):

Just change the first line of the `/usr/local/bin/pip` to:

`#!/usr/bin/python`

and the first line of `/usr/local/bin/pip3` to:

`#!/usr/bin/python3`

And then it will act normally:

```
> pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
> pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (python 3.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This deserves more upvotes.

Comment: I realize this answer is old, but I'm struggling with this, too. I'm having the same issue. Both pip and pip3 point to python3.8. You mention to change the lines, but I'm a newb and I'm afraid to mess something up by typing in the wrong command. Could you please show an example of the whole command? I understand that it involves `#!/usr/bin/python` and `!#/usr/bun/python`,  but I'm not sure what goes before those commands.

Comment: @Nunchuk the first line of a bash script usually points to what should the OS use to execute the file. First navigate to `/usr/bin` and check the different python versions you have with `ls python*` for me I can see `python3.10` and `python3.9`.
Now to find which pip file you want to edit use `which pip` or `which pip3` depending on what you need to change. Go to that file and change the first line to point to the correct python version. For me I have `~/.local/bin/pip`, I went there and changed the first line from `#!/usr/bin/python3.9` to `#!/usr/bin/python3.10`.

Comment: @MohamedYasser Thanks! Kinda embarrassed that I had to ask this question. I appreciate you taking the time to answer. It helped me out.

Comment: @Nunchuk Don't be embarrassed. This is a standard question, and I had that same concern at one point. The most important thing is to ask clear questions and provide answers when you are able to; that's the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 5):

```
python -m pip
```

This will use the version of pip that python can see.

Answer (score 1):

Your local install of python3's pip in /usr/local/bin/ shadows the system install of pip in /usr/bin. In order to use the system's default pip, you can:

- Specify the path explicitly: `sudo /usr/bin/pip install shade`
- Delete the local install of `pip`: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pip`
- Change your $PATH to prefer `/usr/bin` to `/usr/local/bin`
- Use the `pip2` alias from `/usr/bin`: `sudo pip2 install shade`
- Install `python3` from the system repositories: `sudo apt-get install python3`. Don't forget to delete your local `python3` install if you go this route.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem (where pip got associated with Python 3) and it's due to the pip installer updating pip to point to Python 3.  I think this is very confusing behavior because historically everyone has associated pip with Python 2 and pip3 with Python 3.  We got around this by doing the following:

```
# install pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o /tmp/get-pip.py
sudo python3 /tmp/get-pip.py
sudo python /tmp/get-pip.py # install the python2 version last so the pip binary is not overwritten with the python3 version
rm /tmp/get-pip.py
```

The key here is installing the Python 2 pip after installing the Python 3 pip.

Comment: Nice addendum, albeit it is really time to get over python2 by now, and tell any user that from hereon, your stuff only supports python3. Let bygones be bygones ;-)

Comment: Agreed!  Too bad I figured this out so late in the game :)